# how do i create database using entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I followed very simple [example](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) from `www.asp.net` to create Web API project using `Empty` project template for `Web API`.  This tutorial does not create database instead it just create `model` class and seed data inside `api controller.`
I successfully consumed API controller using angular service and able to show data on UI. Till here everything is fine.

However, moving one step further i would like create database but not sure about the steps.

I don't want to follow some other tutorial available on same site which does all of these things because i am not understand the overall concept even though i'll able to create database. Also, tutorial talks about using MVC approach which i dont want to use. I just looking for Web API, EF and Angular combination.

Can someone guide me for writing context class and overall database creation steps.?

Comment: it's hard to believe you use DbContext (or ObjectContext) without involving some database (either created first as in database first or created later as in code-first and model-first). But I guess maybe the api mocks up the DbContext with some fake data, so no database is required. If you want to create the database you can try accessing to the `ObjectContext` and use the method `CreateDatabase`. Maybe you still need to understand how the api controller works and checks how it affects the DbContext.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that shows Web API + EF: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1

Comment: thanks it is helpful.